# Converting Object retrieve from API into DateTime Format

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, object, type-conversion

This is the data that i called from sharepoint by using API

[object datatype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLUYm.png)

then i tried to convert the object into datetime format. but it return NaN value

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxwpu.png)

this is the code that i tried

```
.subscribe((dataChart) => {
    console.log(dataChart)
    console.log(typeof(dataChart))

    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    var str=dataChart.strRequestDate;   //Set the string in the proper format(best to use ISO format ie YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS)
    var d=new Date(str);  //converts the string into date object
    var m=d.getMonth(); //get the value of month
    console.log(m) // Print the month name
      
    },
```

Can anyone point out my mistake

**EDIT:**
list of item appear after i console log e as per @N.F instructions

[new log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrFtq.png)

Answer (score 0):

`dataChart` looks array. You have to use `for` loop to get each element.

```
.subscribe((dataChart) => {
    console.log(dataChart);
    console.log(typeof(dataChart));

    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    
    for (const e of dataChart) {
      var str=e.strRequestDate;   //Set the string in the proper format(best to use ISO format ie YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS)
      var d=new Date(str);  //converts the string into date object
      var m=d.getMonth(); //get the value of month
      console.log(m) // Print the month name
    
    }
      
  },
```

Comment: i run the loop. this time it return 401 item as undefined. what does it mean ?

Comment: What do you see when changing `console.log(m)` to `console.log(str)` ?

Comment: still the same 401 undefined item

Comment: Then what do you see in case `console.log(e)`;

Comment: i have updated in my question. a list of item appear in the console log

Comment: Mmm it's a mystery... `str` must not be undefined.